# Can Java be used for developing games for Android in Unity3D

Tags: unity, java, android, game-design, unityscript

I only know Java Programming Language and no other. Can I develop games for Android in Unity3D using Java?

Comment: When you know Java you already know 95% of C#.

Comment: @Philipp really? If yes, than it'll be amazing.

Comment: @Philipp It's gone up 5% since the last time this question was asked :)

Answer (score 2):

Unity does not natively support Java. There is scripting support for JavaScript, C# and Boo though. If you know Java the jump to C# is not that big.

Also see this [SO.SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4990225/1947205).

There however, seems to be a trick via a manual IKVM conversion from JAR to DLL that can work: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15308/can-i-access-java-code-from-unity.html#